# YII queries not working

Tags: php, yii

I have a table with around 700,000 rows.

```
Profile::model()->findAll("country='US'")
```

I used this to find all rows that have 'US' as its country. But the execution stopped and I didn't get any result. But then I added limit like below

```
Profile::model()->findAll("country='US' limit 10000")
```

then it worked.

why the execution stopped? Please help me.. I'm new to YII.

Comment: Because there were so many records that you ran out of memory? In any case, this question is meaningless without more information as we 'll just be guessing. Put your application in debug mode and have at it.

Comment: what more information is needed ? '$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('t.country = :country');
$criteria->params[':country'] = 'US';
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Profile',array('criteria'=>$criteria));' used this.. then it is working

Comment: The error messages from your server logs would be a good start. Did you put the app in debug mode?

Comment: $criteria = new CDbCriteria(); $criteria->addCondition('t.country = :country'); $criteria->params[':country'] = 'US'; $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Profile',array('criteria'=>$criteria)); used this and got output. I need to know why it is not work with findAll()

Answer (score 2):

If you use `findAll`, then all records will be returned without any limit applied. However, `CActiveDataProvider` automatically paginates results if you don't tell it otherwise. As mentioned in the comments, you are likely running out of memory when using `findAll`. Using a limit or pagination (which automatically applies a limit) lowers the returned number of rows to what your application can handle.

I recommend using [CDataProviderIterator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProviderIterator) to fetch large numbers of active records. Try the following sample code.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('country','US');

$Profiles = CDataProviderIterator(
   new CActiveDataProvider(
     'Profile',
      array('criteria'=>$criteria)
   ),
   10000
 );

foreach ($Profiles as $Profile) {
  //do whatever
}
```

Using the iterator, Yii will automatically fetch just 10000 records (a number you say worked without running out of memory) at a time, and then remove them from memory before grabbing the next page. Conveniently all the records can be accessed with a `foreach` loop without any further work from you.

Change the 10000 value as necessary to achieve desired results. Also, make sure you are monitoring your error logs to identify out of memory and other errors.