# Getting all records stops the script

Tags: php, yii

I have a php function that take all records of a table in my DB.

When my records are become more than 20'000 this function stopped to work.

If i execute`$all = MyModel::model()->findAll();` the script fail, I dont know why.

But placing a Limit `$all = MyModel::model()->findAllBySql('select * from tableName limit 10000');` all works well.

If i set the limit over 15'000 (more or less) is not working anymore.

I dont know why the problem is generated. 
Maybe for the memory usage with the variable where I store the records?
A Database timeout? (it not takes too long to fetch all rows: 3-4 seconds)

Someone knows the answer? There is a workaround for this?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18679817/2600397

Willem Renzema advise the use of [CDataProviderIterator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProviderIterator) because this doesn't hold the full set of records in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you come over the `memory_limit` from PHP. You can check it in your apache log file. There you can see something like

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of *** bytes exhausted
```

I would prefer to implement an Iterator Interface. Then you can go through the data step by step and you don't need to save all records in one variable.

http://php.net/manual/de/class.iteratoraggregate.php 
http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.iterator.php