# mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_num_rows in query builder in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a query in yii framework that I want to convert to the query builder

Part of code:

```
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM `mosqueculturalliablee` WHERE `email` ='$this->username'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql,$connect);
        if ($query === FALSE) {
            trigger_error(mysql_error());
        }
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows!=0)
        {
            //while loop
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $email = $row["email"];
                $password = $row["password"];
            }
```

I convert the first two lines in this way:

```
          $query =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select ()
        ->from('mosqueculturalliablee')
        ->where("email='" . $this->username."'")
                ->queryAll();
```

My problem is with `mysql_num_rows($query)` and  `mysql_fetch_assoc($query)` the error says that `$query` is an `array` and it is not allowed.

So, how can I convert these to the query builder expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[queryAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryAll-detail) returns all rows of the query result. So you could do:

```
$query =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select ()
        ->from('mosqueculturalliablee')
        ->where("email='" . $this->username."'")
                ->queryAll();
$totalRows = count($query); //get returned rows count
```

and to loop, do:

```
foreach($query as $row) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: A time may come when you will have too many records for this to work. A solution may be to use 2 queries, one to count and another to obtain the records. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675874/yii-queries-not-working/18679817#18679817

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment this due to low rep, but: Please do not construct queries like that as they are prone to SQL injection attacks. Here's the right way:

```
$results=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM mosqueculturalliablee WHERE `email`=:email')
->queryAll(array(
    ':email'=>$this->username,
));
```

Comment: but an error occurred:    CDbConnection and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "createFindCommand".

Comment: Sorry, I typed that freehand. I just changed my answer to something that should work.